# GoDaddy Send Email

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.0

I am using ASP.Net 4.0 with MVC 3 and C# to try and send an email from my site. This code works on other hosts but for some reason GoDaddy is erroring out. Here is the code I am using.

```
  var fAddress = new MailAddress("customers@email.com");
  var tAddress = new MailAddress("mygodaddyaddress@email.com");
  var message = new MailMessage(fAddress, tAddress)
  {
      Subject = subject,
      Body = body
  };

  var client = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net");
  client.Send(message);
```

Here is the error I am receiving

> Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: sorry, your mail was administratively denied. (#5.7.1)

Any other GoDaddy users here that can shed some light?

Comment: Turns out I had to make sure the from address was my GoDaddy email address something GoDaddy requires unlike my other hosts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [send smtp email through godaddy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032860/send-smtp-email-through-godaddy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be something to do with the from address:

> Problem seem to be the FROM email address. The FROM email address must be an email address with the hosted domain to avoid this error. For example if you have a hosted domain yourdomain.com, your FROM email address should be something like username@yourdomain.com.

Source:
http://www.cosmocentral.com/2009/01/553-sorry-your-mail-was-administratively-denied/

Comment: This was correct I had to make sure the from address was my GoDaddy email address something GoDaddy requires unlike my other hosts.

Comment: @GregGoodwin and Mun, I know this answer is correct and forever old but since this is the first google result, and for the sake of completeness, here is the official godaddy support thread on the subject.  `You’ll want to use relay-hosting.secureserver.net on port 25 as your SMTP relay server, and do not specify a username or password. Additionally, do not specify the FROM address in the message header, as if it appears as an email not hosted by us (i.e. Hotmail, Gmail, etc.), then our system will block it.` http://support.godaddy.com/groups/email/forum/topic/send-mail-by-coding-in-asp-net/

Answer (score 1):

It could be because neither email address is native to the mail server used by GoDaddy, and thus you'd need to allow relaying. This is just one possibility, I think the best approach would be to contact them directly.

Comment: This was correct I had to make sure the from address was my GoDaddy email address something GoDaddy requires unlike my other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Your From address does not need to be a GoDaddy email.  It is the user/password for the domain that must be valid.  This is what the Web.config should have:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="me@test.com">
      <network host="smtpout.secureserver.net" port="80" userName="foo@bar.com" password="yourpassword" defaultCredentials="false" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Then you can initialize it in code-behind with this:

```
var mailclient = new SmtpClient();
```